# How to make simple watchlist from a running list of tickers with python?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, stock, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to gather tickers that close above the previous day close from a small list of tickers during a specific time period using python?  I am coming up with No data based on my conditions written below but when I look manual I know the conditions are true for ABML on 12-7-21.  I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.  Thanks for looking at it!

AXXA
GNUS
ABML
ILUS
ENGA

'''''''

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter

yf.pdr_override()
start = dt.datetime(2021, 11, 30)
now = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 15) # dt.datetime.now()

filePath = ('your file path')

stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath)
stocklist = stocklist.head()

#*************************************************************************

exportList = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock', "Date", "Open"])

for i in stocklist.index:
    stock = str(stocklist["Symbol"][i])
    #RS_Rating = stocklist["RS Rating"][i]

try:
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, now)

        PreviousClose = df["Close"][-1]
        CurrentClose = df["Close"][0]
        CurrentDate = df["Date"][0]
        CurrentOpen = df["Open"][0]

        # Condition 1: Explain your criteria
        if (PreviousClose < CurrentClose):
            cond_1 = True
        else:
            cond_1 = False
        # Condition 2: Explain your criteria
        if (PreviousClose < CurrentClose):
            cond_2 = True
        else:
            cond_2 = False

        if (cond_1 and cond_2):
            exportList = exportList.append({'Stock': stock, "Date": CurrentDate, "Open": CurrentOpen}, ignore_index=True)

except Exception:
    print("No data on " + stock)


print(exportList)

newFile = os.path.dirname(filePath) + "/ScreenOutput.xlsx"

writer = ExcelWriter(newFile)
exportList.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1")
writer.save()
```